# Table fixed head with two tables have alignment issue with scrollbar on tbody

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have added two tables to make `thead` section as fixed on the top.
The contents in the table (`tbody`) comes from database. So, the number of rows may have small or large number of rows.

**Consider this code.**

If `tbody` have few rows:

```css
.tables {
  padding: 20px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.table-head table thead tr th:last-child {
  width: 15%;
}

.tables .table-body {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-body table tbody tr td:last-child {
  width: 15%;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right: -10px;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

.tbl-fieldList .tbl-body-only::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <div class="table-head">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="table-body">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

If `tbody` has large number of rows, the alignment of the table `th` and `td` gets distorted:

```css
.tables {
  padding: 20px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.table-head table thead tr th:last-child {
  width: 15%;
}

.tables .table-body {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-body table tbody tr td:last-child {
  width: 15%;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right: -10px;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

.tbl-fieldList .tbl-body-only::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <div class="table-head">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="table-body">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I have tried to make the custom scroll bar position to outside of the div, but it is not working.** Anybody have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Would you consider using JavaScript/jQuery? If yes 
`if ($('.table-body table).outerHeight() > 200) {$('.table-head').css('overflow','scroll')}`

Comment: No problem If using JavaScript.. I will try with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the custom scroll to 'table-head' and then add few lines of JavaScript :)

```js
if (document.querySelector('.table-body table').offsetHeight > 200) { // same as max-height
    document.querySelector('.table-head').style.overflowY = 'scroll';
}
```

```css
.tables {
  padding: 20px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.table-head table thead tr th:last-child {
  width: 15%;
}

.tables .table-body {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-body table tbody tr td:last-child {
  width: 15%;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar,
.table-head::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right: -10px;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.table-head::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

.tbl-fieldList .tbl-body-only::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <div class="table-head">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="table-body">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sample name</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working in normal HTML but, Shows an error in code --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null

Comment: @vishnu Make sure you run the JavaScript after you load the table, and then on every reload of the data in the table